# Where can I find QSS for button and more?

Tags: qt, qpushbutton, qtstylesheets

I really want QPushButton like this website ( http://www.cssbuttongenerator.com/ ) generate. But it's impossible because lots of thing are not supported in QT.

So can you tell me if there's a good database for QPushButton stylesheet ?

Comment: Can you give an example of something that cannot be done with Qt qss?

Comment: Yes of course, for example : filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf');
 background-color:#ededed;
 -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
 -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;

Comment: So basically it is just a gradient and round corners? If so you can just use:

background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, 
                                  stop:0 white, stop:1 rgb(90,90,90));
border-radius: 3px;

Comment: I have posted an answer to your question, if it is useful please accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fail to see what cannot be done using QSS in Qt.

For instance in case of a gradient or rounded corner:

```
background-color: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, 
                                 stop:0 white, stop:1 rgb(90,90,90));
border-radius: 3px;
```

If you really need a special drawing, you can always use QPainter.